# Can't access class attribute within html and angular

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

For some reason I can't access a class attribute when looping a list in html inside a angular's ngFor.

The error I'm getting is `Property 'User' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'`, when I've clearly imported the file and I'm using it without any problems inside app.component.ts.

At the moment I have this, which is creating the error in `User.filteredusers`. Also, I've included the Users class in the typescript file I'm using.

**app.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of User.filteredUsers |
    paginate: {
      itemsPerPage: resultsPerPage,
      currentPage: page,
      totalItems: totalLength
    }">
  <th scope="row">{{ user.id }}</th>
  <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.contact }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.login }}</td>
</tr>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
// ...
import { User } from './user.model';
// ...
```

**user.model.ts**

```
export class User{
    // ...
    static filteredUsers = new Array<User>();
    // ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i can see is that you are trying to access the class "User" in your app.component.html.
You will have to define a variable in you app.component.ts from type "User" and than you can access the variable:

Here an example:

```
export class Document implements OnInit {
  user: User;
```

**Update**
So i tried it myself, and it worked the way i told. Even if a variable in a class is static, you cannot access the class itself in html without declaring a variable in the component of the template.

**Solution 1**
user.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss'],
})

export class UserComponent {
  static filteredUsers = ["test","test2"];
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {UserComponent} from "./user/user.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  user = UserComponent;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor = "let user of user.filteredUsers">
  {{user}}
</div>
```

**Solution 2:**
Another way would be to create a function in your app.component.ts where you access the "User.filteredUsers" and return them.

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  getFilteredUser(){
    return UserComponent.filteredUsers
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor = "let user of getFilteredUser()">
  {{user}}
</div>
```

Comment: I created a dummyUser and tried dummyUser.filteredUsers, and as expected it didn't work giving me this error: ```Property 'filteredUsers' does not exist on type 'User'. Did you mean to access the static member 'User.filteredUsers' instead?```. But since the list is a static attribute though, why can't I access it with User.filteredUsers?

Comment: I updated my solution. Even if the variable in the class is static, you cannot access the class "User" in html

Comment: I used your 2nd solution, it works like a charm, thank you!